# linear probability from non-linear one

Tags: algorithm, probability

here is my problem.

Imagine you've got a function like that : (here in C )

```
int strangeRand() {
    if ( rand() % 100 <= 70 ) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

This one return 0 a probability of 0.7
and 1 with a probability of 0.3

Here is what i want to do, create a function that return 0 with a probability of 0.5 and 1 with a probability of 0.5 too.

I need to only use strangeRand() function [Can't modify it] (and loop, and if etc but no rand() function )

Is someone got an idea, how to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a solved problem!  It's usually known as getting a [fair result from an unfair coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_coin#Fair_results_from_a_biased_coin).

The algorithm works as follows:

1. Call the function twice.
2. If the results match, start over, forgetting both results.
3. If the results differ, use the first result, forgetting the second.

The provided link contains an explanation of *why* the algorithm works.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I think that's what i'm looking for :D (i'll accept your answer in seven minute can't do it before )

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KUN5x5vU here is a quit implementation of what you said and that's work really great. Thanks again